# Bootstrap : Dropdown in top navbar in fixed place

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to make dropdown in top navbar. And I want to show the dropdown content in fixed place.

**Dropdown box of each navitem shown in different places.**

Here the picture of dropdown content of left most navitem. **I want to show the dropdown box of all navitem in this place.**

[image: dropdown content of left most navitem]

Here the picture of dropdown content of 5th navitem. But dropdown box show in right side of that navitem.

[image: dropdown content of navitem]

Navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav category-nav">
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-right&#58;#fff 1px solid;color:white;">Electronics</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li><a href="#">subcategory1</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory1</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory2 ....</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" >subcategory2</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory</a></li>                
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">subcategory3</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory</a></li>                
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">subcategory4</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory1</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory2 ....</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" >subcategory5</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory</a></li>                
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">subcategory6</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:black">sub_subcategory</a></li>                
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </li>
... .... ...
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-right&#58;#fff 1px solid;color:white;">Food</a>
....
   </ul>
 </div>

</nav>
```

Jquery to hieght and width of dropdown content:

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu').css("width",$('.category-nav').width());
$('.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu').css("max-height","300px");
```

Answer (score 1):

change properties of dropdown menu in css

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: fixed !important;
/*left: 25% !important;*/
top:146px;
display: none;

}
```

to centralize dropdown-menu and set width add this jquery

```
var ddw = $('.category-nav').width();//set ddw to width of navbar
$('.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu').css("width",ddw);
$('.dropdown-menu').css("left",($(window).width()-ddw)/2);//centralise dropdown menu
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css("left",($(window).width()-ddw)/2);//centralise dropdown menu during resizing window
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that the position of the `ul.nav > li > ul` is relative to the `ul.nav > li`.
This should be removed in your CSS and you should instead add `position:relative;` to your `ul.nav`

Then you're a step closer. But i can only provide more Help if you can show me your CSS.
Or better the live example.

Comment: there is no item like ul.nav > li > ul or ul.nav > li in my main.css file. I think, want to change default properties of dropdown in bootstrap.css file.

Comment: Yes, by overwriting them like i said :P